# Alternative of this loop in C for(i=0,j=10;i<j;i++,j--) in python

Tags: python-3.x

I tried this

```
mylist=['+','-','+','-']

for i in range(0,len(mylist)-1):

    k=ord(mylist[i])

    if(k is ord("+")or(k is ord("-"))):

        del mylist[i]

        i=0
```

but it exits after one iteration.

I want to search from starting to end every time
So can we pass variable in `range()`?

Comment: Why not `mylist = [x for x in mylist if x not in '+-']` ?

Comment: And don't get in the habit of comparing ints using "is"; sometimes it works, but only as an implementation optimization. Save "is" for comparisons with None, or other defined singletons (either builtin or your own).

Answer (score 1):

deleting from the list you are iterating over is almost never a good idea. your counter increases while your list shrinks.

in python it is preferable to loop over the items of the list themselves and not over an index.

you could solve your problem with a [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
res = [c for c in mylist if c not in '+-']
```